# shall I include a file to seperate functioniality in PHP, or are there better ways?

Tags: php, class, oop, procedural

Is there a way to implement this idea

```
class Test{

  public function test(){
    return include 'test.php';
  }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
   // process the functions here (including queries , etc)
   return 1;
?>
```

Test

```
$test = new Test();
echo $test->test();
```

Basically, it's a combination of OOP and Procedural approach. The main goal here is to separate the process of the functions and put it on another file. The purpose is lessen the lines of the code from the class and make it easier to trace instead of scrolling to 1000+ lines of codes.

PS. I'm sorry for the title. I am not sure if this is possible but I hope you could give me idea.

Thanks and Have a nice day!

Comment: _Basically, it's a combination of OOP and Procedural approach_ Don't do this. It usually never has a happy ending. If you wish to have separate files for utility functions, make it as a different file(like you did) and autoload them.

Comment: All about autoloading with composer you will find here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading , because @nice_dev made a good point !

Comment: Basically you should split this 1000 lines class into 10 classes each in a distinct file, loaded using autoload.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to aggregate an other class (which can sit in an other file) and call a method of this:

Main Class: Test.php

```php
<?php
use namespace\path\to\OtherClass;
//or require_once("path/to/OtherClass.php");
class Test 
{
 
   public function test() 
   {
      $otherClass = new OtherClass();
      return $otherClass->otherCall();
   }
}
```

while the other class will look like this (`OtherClass.php`):

```php
<?php
class OtherClass
{
   public function otherCall()
   {
      return "some value";
   }
}
```

#### Further ...

if you have a class which you want to mix in your classes, you can use the concept of mixins, which are called [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) in php.

The `OtherClass.php` will change to

```php
<?php
trait OtherClass
{
   public function otherCall()
   {
      return "some value";
   }
}
```

and the `Test.php` class would change to:

```php
<?php
use namespace\path\to\OtherClass;
//or require_once("path/to/OtherClass.php");
class Test
{
   use OtherClass;
 
   public function test() 
   {
      return $this->otherCall();
   }
}
```

If you are new to OOP or Programming I can reccomand two books by Robert Martin:

"Clean Code" and "Clean Architecture".

And to get better in PhP I can recommand this website: https://phptherightway.com/

Comment: Is it possible to have a callback function from Test class to OtherClass ?

e.g

class Test{
    public function test(){
      return include 'test.php';
   }

   public function otherTest(){
      return 1;
   }
}

test.php

class OtherClass{
   public function returnThis(){
     return Test->otherTest();
  }
}

something like this?

Comment: @Komskie would you PLEASE provide some concrete use case instead of all those "tests"? It's hard to provide an answer to this kind of vague question. Also. if you have another question then you must ask another question instead of adding up to the existing one

Comment: @Komskie try out what I posted, and see if that fits your case. Try to lose your point of view, as it is obviously not a best practice nor are you an experienced developer.  It wont work your way. This is total ok, when you are a beginner and I am an expert. I adept to ideas from people too, that are more skilled than I am - and there are a lot.